# How to take only time from this 2018-01-25T20:30:02.533+0000?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime, dataframe

So this is one columns in my dataframe. i want to replace whole string with the time only.

So from above string , i only want to extract 20:30:02 in long format.
I know, how to convert into long, but how to extract time is i am not getting in python.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: 20:30:02.533, as you can see in 2018-01-25T20:30:02.533+0000 ,  time is 20:30:02.533 only.

Comment: No, it is not happening. giving error. KeyError: 'delivery_done_at'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2018-01-25T20:30:02.533+0000','2018-01-25T20:30:02.533+0000']})

df['date1'] = df['date'].str[11:19]
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.floor('S').dt.time
print (df)
                           date     date1     date2
0  2018-01-25T20:30:02.533+0000  20:30:02  20:30:02
1  2018-01-25T20:30:02.533+0000  20:30:02  20:30:02

print (df.applymap(type))
            date          date1                    date2
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'datetime.time'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'datetime.time'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
df["time"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
print(df["time"])
```

Assuming `df["date"]` is your column that holds the datetime values.

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
d = parse('2018-01-25T20:30:02.533+0000')
d.hour, d.minute, d.second
```

Comment: But , it is in dataFrame, your answer is not for dataframe. but nice try